# Prove that if $ \bar R$ is symmetric then $ R $ is symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**EDIT:** $\bar R$ means $\bar R = \{ (a,b) | (a,b) \notin  R\}$

**Problem:** Prove that if the relation $ \bar R$ is symmetric then the relation $ R $ is symmetric for any given set.

**Proof**:

Let $(a,b) \in \bar R$.

If $(a,b) \in \bar R \land (b,a) \in \bar R$, then  $(a,b) \notin R \land (b,a) \notin R$.

I can't move beyond this. Any ideas?

Comment: So $R$ is a relation on some set and $\overline{R}$ is its set-theoretic complement?

Comment: R is a relation. $\bar R$ means $\bar R = \{ (a,b) | (a,b) \notin  R\}$

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $R$ is symmetric. That is, if $(a,b) \in R$ then $(b, a) \in R$. If this is not the case, then $(a,b) \in R$ but $(b, a) \notin R$. So $(b, a) \in \overline{R}$. But $\overline{R}$ is symmetric and you can show that this leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b)\in R$. Then $(a,b)\not\in \bar R$. By symmetry of $\bar R$, $(b,a)\not\in \bar R$. Thus $(b,a)\in R$. Done.